# Grep order from file

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have 2 files.
In first file i have teplates that i want to found in second filed.
How i must use grep for save order like it in first file in output.
example:

**file1:**
a
dc
as

**file2:**
aadfadf
asdva
vaad
a
dccsads
asas

I use this command:
`grep -f file1 file2 >> file3`

Comment: Could you show what you expect the output to be in your example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a little bit slow but quite simple:

```
TEMP1=$(mktemp /tmp/grep.XXXXXXXXXXX)
TEMP2=$(mktemp /tmp/grep.XXXXXXXXXXX)
cat file2 > $TEMP1
cat file1 | while read line
do 
  grep "$line" $TEMP1
  grep -v "$line" $TEMP1 > $TEMP2
  mv $TEMP2 $TEMP1
done > result
rm $TEMP2 $TEMP1
```

Resulting list in `result`.

I use the temporary files `$TEMP1` and `$TEMP2` and `grep -v` to avoid duplicates in the result.

Comment: Note that you will get duplicates when one pattern is a substring/submatch of another.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: No, Aaron! I use grep -v for that

Comment: That fixes the issue but isn't "very simple" anymore ;-)

Comment: This answer is very old but helped me now a lot. Thank you So much..

Comment: @ThulasiR: Well, it is not so old comparing to that how old is `grep` :)